# tree command failing strangely with some patterns

Tags: tree

I have the following directory:

```
❯ tree -p
.
└── [drwxr-xr-x]  dir
    ├── [-rw-r--r--]  a.ml
    ├── [-rw-r--r--]  a.o
    ├── [-rw-r--r--]  b.ml
    └── [-rw-r--r--]  b.o
```

If I try to filter tree can't find anything:

```
❯ tree -p -P *.ml
zsh: no matches found: *.ml
❯ tree -p -P *ml
zsh: no matches found: *ml
```

And if I go in the directory `dir`:

```
❯ tree -p -P *.ml
b.ml [error opening dir]

0 directories, 0 files
❯ tree -p -P *ml
b.ml [error opening dir]

0 directories, 0 files
```

Am I not seeing something obvious here? Why does it fail and how can I fix it?

Comment: I guess your shell tries to interpret `*.ml`, see the error message, its not `tree` that is complaining. Put the pattern in quotes and it should work fine.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! My issue was the "error opening dir" that I got first and it's a tree error if I'm not mistaken. But yes, quotes work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to quote your pattern, otherwise it will be interpreted by the shell instead of `tree`.

This should work fine:

```sh
tree -p -P '*.ml'
```